# Suppose X and Y are independent random variables, each distributed as N(0,1). Suppose a>0. Compute that $E[X \max(0, X, aY)]$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose X and Y are independent random variables, each distributed as N(0,1). Suppose a>0. Compute that $E[X \max(0, X, aY)]$

My attempt:

$E[X \max(0, X, aY)] = 0 P(0 is  \max) + E[X^2] P(X is \max) + E[aXY] P(aY is \max)$

I don't know whether my above idea is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not quite correct, because the expectations must also be conditioned.  So it should look like this:

$$\operatorname{E}[X \max(0, X, aY)] = \operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid X > aY > 0] \Pr[X > aY > 0] + \operatorname{E}[aXY \mid aY > X > 0]\Pr[aY > X > 0].$$

However, this doesn't really get us very far.  Instead, it is better to consider the joint density $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}, \tag{1}$$ and the function $$g(X,Y) = X \max(0, X, aY). \tag{2}$$  Then
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X \max(0, X, aY)] 
&= \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty g(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy. \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
We then consider the region of the $xy$-plane for which $g(x,y) = 0$, $x^2$, and $axy$, respectively.  Clearly, $g = 0$ when both $x \le 0$ and $y \le 0$.  When $y = x/a > 0$, then $g = x^2 = axy$.  To the left of this ray, $g = axy$, and below the ray, $g = x^2$.  So this divides the plane into three regions, namely
$$g(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0, y \le 0 \\
x^2, & 0 < ay \le x \\
axy, & 0 < x \le ay.
\end{cases} \tag{4}$$  Then our integral $(3)$ becomes
$$2\pi \operatorname{E}[g(X,Y)] = \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=-\infty}^{x/a} x^2 e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, dy \, dx + \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=-\infty}^{ay} axy e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} \, dx \, dy. \tag{5}$$
I leave it as an exercise for you to verify that the RHS of $(5)$ evaluates to $$\frac{\pi}{2} + \cot^{-1} a$$ from which the desired expectation immediately follows.